# $C^{k}$ topologies on $ Hol(U)$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, several-complex-variables

Consider $U\subset \mathbb C^{n}$, an open domain and denote by $Hol(U)$ the space of holomorphic complex valued functions defined on $U$.
Prove that the topologies induced by $C^{k}$ uniform convergence on compacts are all the same.
One inclusion is trivial and for the other inclusion I think it is sufficient to show that $T_1 = T_0$, because you can do a recursive argument with the partial derivatives. where $T_k$ represents the respective topology. But i do not know how to prove it.

**Note**
Since every holomorphic functions is analytic, does this result implies that the partial derivatives are continuous?

Comment: Use Cauchy's integral fórmula for the derivatives

Comment: Which one is it? The one that gives you the coefficients of the series expansion?

Comment: The one to which the Wikipedia page with title "Cauchy's integral formula" is dedicated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the sequence $(f_n)_{n\geq0}$ of holomorphic functions on $U$ converges uniformly on compact sets of $U$ to $f$, let $k\geq1$ and let us show that the sequence $(f_n^{(k)})_{n\geq0}$ of the $k$th derivatives converges uniformly on compact sets of $U$ to $f^{(k)}$.

Let $p\in U$, let $B$ be a closed disc centered at $p$ and contained in $U$ and let $\gamma$ be the boundary of a closed disc centered at $p$ which contains $B$ in its interior and is itself contained in $U$. Let $\rho$ be the absolute value of difference of the radii of $B$ and $\gamma$: we then have $|t-z|\geq\rho$ for all $t\in\gamma$ and all $z\in B$.

According to Cauchy's integral formulas, for all functions $g$ holomorphic on $U$ we have that $$g^{(k)}(z) = \frac{k!}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{g(t)}{(t-z)^{k+1}}\,\mathrm dt$$ for all $z\in B$. In particular, we have for such $z$ that $$f^{(k)}(z)-f^{(k)}(z)=\frac{k!}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma\frac{f_n(t)-f(t)}{(t-z)^{k+1}}\,\mathrm dt,$$ so that
$$
|f^{(k)}(z)-f^{(k)}(z)|
\leq\frac{k!\operatorname{length(\gamma)}}{2\pi}\sup_{t\in\gamma}\left|\frac{f_n(t)-f(t)}{(t-z)^{k+1}}\right|
\leq\frac{k!\operatorname{length(\gamma)}}{2\pi\rho^{k+1}}\sup_{t\in\gamma}|f_n(t)-f(t)|
$$
for all $\in B$. As $f_n$ converges to $f$ uniformly on the compact set $\gamma$, we see that $f_n^{(k)}$ converges uniformly to $f^{(k)}$ on $B$.

It follows that we have uniform convergence of all derivatives on all closed balls contained in $U$ and, therefore, on all compact subsets of $U$.

Comment: Thanks, I was having a little trouble for the bound of $\frac {1}{|t-z|}$ using nested disks never passed through my mind, the cool thing is that this generalizes quite straight forward to several complex variables. Also, in proof is clear that the derivative, as an operator, is continuous.